# Not able to click an element in saved form in Mocha framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, mocha.js

Requesting you to plz help on this .
I am using MOCHA and chai fW for my testing here .Here i have one saved form namely formula and i am trying to click an element with clickElement(driver,By.xpath('//*[@id="clsmyGrid"]')) but it is not working . I had an option to create a new form and it starts working with same code i mean i am able to click an element. Here i saved this form and it is not picking the id to click the element.

```
  it('Searching for satistics row', done => {
           setTimeout(function () {
                clickElement(driver,By.xpath('//*[@id="clsmyGrid"]')).then(function(){
                   done();
               });
           }, executionPauseTime)
       });

function clickElement(driver,by){
  var ele = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by), large);
  return ele.click().then(function(res){
     chai.assert.isOk(true);
  }, function(error) {
    chai.assert.fail(error.message)
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML for the page you are trying to automate? This will help us troubleshoot your issue better.